# Pandas: Miscounting Number of Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas in a Jupyter notebook.  I have a dataframe, `result_df`, containing a column `_text`.  I'm trying to filter out rows satisfying a certain condition (specifically ones where number of words in result_df[`_text`] is 0).

When I start, I have this:

```
len(result_df)
```

and I get back:

```
49708
```

Then I do this:

```
result_df[result_df['_text'].apply(textstat.lexicon_count) != 0]
```

In the notebook, I see a huge dataframe with this at the bottom:

```
49701 rows × 5 columns
```

*However*, when I run:

```
len(result_df)
```

I get back:

```
49708
```

So now I'm very confused: it looks like I've removed 7 rows but the `len` function disagrees...

Any clarification would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're overwriting your dataframe with the new objects?  IE `df_new = df_old[condition]`

Comment: @AdamHughes I thought that my code would change the dataframe in place...

Comment: @bclayman It does not.

Comment: Almost all pandas operations are not in place

Answer (score 3):

Overwriting will help. Use this line of code:

```
result_df = result_df[result_df['_text'].apply(textstat.lexicon_count) != 0]
len(result_df)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have done is simply obtained a view of the original data frame using boolean indexing. No change was made. As an example:

```
In [108]: df
Out[108]: 
   colx  coly name
0     1     5  foo
1     2     6  foo
2     3     7  bar
3     4     8  bar

In [109]: len(df)
Out[109]: 4
```

Now, index to find all rows with `colx` > 3:

```
In [110]: df[df['colx'] > 3]
Out[110]: 
   colx  coly name
3     4     8  bar

In [111]: len(df[df['colx'] > 3])
Out[111]: 1
```

However, if you print out the original df:

```
In [112]: df
Out[112]: 
   colx  coly name
0     1     5  foo
1     2     6  foo
2     3     7  bar
3     4     8  bar
```

If you want to reassign the data frame to the slice, you need to explicitly assign it:

```
result_df = result_df[result_df['_text'].apply(textstat.lexicon_count) != 0]
```